# a good implementation of time-based loop on android

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm having my first try at writing a game for android, and need to write a loop for drawing the animation on canvas. This is basically what I need:

```
every 0.1 seconds do { //0.1 seconds is arbitrary of course, I need a time frame that's good for animation
   every 5 seonds do {
      someStuff();
    }
   drawEverything();
}
```

Can anyone recommend a good way of implementing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ScheduleExecutorService`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

```
Runnable someStuff = new Runnable....

Runnable drawEverything = new Runnable...
```

then, to schedule them:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(someStuff, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(drawEverything, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is much cleaner than using a loop that never ends. Whats nice is that if you have a shutdown hook, or just want to call it directly, is you can call:

```
executor.shutDown()
```

which will complete any pending tasks and then stop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CountDownTimer` class `onTick` method or `Chronometer` class `setOnChronometerTickListener` method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of the Android API you're targeting, and how you're implementing your game.

If you're okay with API level 16 (4.1 / Jellybean) and later, you can use the Choreographer class ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html).

If you're using OpenGL ES, or an engine that provides vsync callbacks, you would want to structure the game differently.  Rather than driving the display with your timing, you let the system drive your game, and events happen based on how much time has elapsed.  See for example the way `GameState.calculateNextFrame()` advances a bouncing ball in http://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/.  This feels less natural, because you're no longer directing traffic, but it's also more "real" because your animation is going to be latched on screen refresh updates.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `View`, implement its `onDraw()` method and do your drawing there. Every time the view hierarchy is invalidated, `onDraw()` will be called:

```
public class MyGameView extends View {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Any tasks that should run every frame can be placed here. For
        // example moving the player and monsters.

        // Draw everything to canvas here.
        canvas.drawBitmap(mPlayerBitmap, mPlayerX, mPlayerY, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mMonsterBitmap, mMonsterX, mMonsterY, null);

        // Either do a invalidate() to draw in maximum frame rate here. Or do
        // postInvalidateDelayed(10) to draw a new frame every 0.1 seconds.
        // onDraw() will automatically be called by the system.
        postInvalidateDelayed(10);
    }
}
```

Your new view can then be added to an existing view hierarchy, containing other things like `Button`s and `TextView`s, using `ViewGroup.addView(myGameView)`. Or it can be set as content view to take up the whole screen, using `Activity.setContentView(myGameView)`.

Reoccurring tasks can be posted through `View.postDelayed()` to ensure that they are run on the same thread as `onDraw()`. A `Runnable` can be posted, which then posts itself again every time its `run()` method is called. It's a good idea to post the task in `Activity.onResume()` and remove it in `Activity.onPause()`, to ensure that nothing runs when your game is in the background:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMyGameView.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMyGameView.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform reoccurring task...

        mMyGameView.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
    }
};
```